# How to call function of one component from another in React

Tags: reactjs

We have 2 class components

```
Component1{
intializeHandler(){}
}

Component2{
}
```

How to use intializeHandler function in component 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define function globally in external folder

```
  --libs        |
                |--functions |
                |            |--intializeHandler.js
  --componenets |
                |--Component1
                |--Component2
```

intializeHandler.js

```
export const intializeHandler = () => {}
```

Component1.js

```
import { intializeHandler  } from "../libs/functions/intializeHandler"
// And use
intializeHandler ()
```

Comment: Yeah this approach works!! .But can we pass intializeHandler function as props in component 1 and call it in component 2?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think... no